# Query multiple Entity attributes with List of values

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I have a List of Strings which contains search items for multiple attributes in an Entity. I would like to Query the database and retrieve any Entity which has one of these Strings in any one of the specified attributes. For instance, say I have a List of partial names:

```
//contents of the list (for visual purposes)
["Mi", "Chr", "Leo", "Jo", "Par"]
```

Also, let us assume that we do not know the size of the list. Now, say I have an Entity with the following attributes:

```
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

How can I retrieve (preferably in one Query) all Entities whose first OR last names contain any of the Strings within the list?

Something like (Pseudo code):

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.firstName LIKE (%Mi% OR %Chr% OR %Leo% OR %Jo% OR %Par%) 
    OR u.lastName LIKE (%Mi% OR %Chr% OR %Leo% OR %Jo% OR %Par%)
```

If there were something like a LIKE IN clause that'd be perfect but, unfortunately, I don't believe JPQL supports that. So, how could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This code builds a query using the `IN` condition.

```
String query = "";
String whereClause = "";

for(int i = 0; i < LIST.size(); i++) {
    // using * wildcard
    whereClause += "\"*" + LIST.get(i).toString() + "*\",";
}

query = String.format("SELECT User.firstName, User.lastName FROM User WHERE User.firstName IN (%s) OR User.lastName IN (%s);", whereClause, whereClause);
```